# How to run production site after build vue cli

Tags: node.js, vuejs2, production-environment, vue-cli

I'm using VueCLI 2 and build as production. THe build.js is built and compiled into 200KB. When I re-run the server as development, it loaded 3MB. I'm sure the build.js inside dist folder is 200KB. I tried to open index.html but it doesn't work and redirect to root directory on website.

**Package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
  "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
},
```

**Webpack**

```
module.exports = { ...
module:{
 ...
 plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
 ],
 devtool: '#eval-source-map'
},
...
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
   new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
     NODE_ENV: '"production"'
   }
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    sourceMap: true,
    compress: {
     warnings: true
    }
  }),
  new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
    minimize: true
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'vendor',
    minChunks: function (module) {
      return module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
    }
  })
 ])
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <script src="/dist/vendor.js"></script>
  <script src="/dist/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Command**

> npm run build
>
> npm run dev

Answer (score 144, accepted):

`npm run build` creates a `dist` directory with a production build of your app.

In order to serve `index.html` in a browser you need an HTTP server.

For example [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve):

```
npm install -g serve
serve -s dist
```

The default port is `5000`, but can be adjusted using the `-l` or `--listen` flags:

```
serve -s build -l 4000
```

Docs:

- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#static-server
- https://github.com/zeit/serve
- https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#previewing-locally

Comment: Thanks a lot was searching this for long. Although the images are not getting loaded. Any idea why?

Comment: Worth to mention - default port is 5000 - if you want to listen on different port use flag `-l` `serve -s dist -l 8080`

Comment: @PrathameshAware: did you solved the image loading problem? I've the same problem !

Comment: It works but the port is always 5000. Do you know how can I change that to something else??

Comment: I am running into CORS issue when I run production build with serve package, but not with development build. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: How can we rewrite all requests to `index.html` to use Vue-Router history mode? See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Answer (score 38):

Production build can be run locally by utilizing Vue CLI's tooling simply by running:

`vue-cli-service serve --mode production`

For convenience, this can be added to package.json scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "production": "vue-cli-service serve --mode production"
  }
```

Command:

```
$ npm run production
```

Comment: Thank You, works just fine!

Comment: This does indeed set `NODE_ENV` to "production".  But to serve the `dist` folder, consider using the `serve` command directly as per other answers.

Answer (score 11):

Very easy with `express`, and highly extensible/configurable.

**Install**

`npm install -D express`

**Compose**

server.js

```
// optional: allow environment to specify port
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080

// wire up the module
const express = require('express') 
// create server instance
const app = express() 
// bind the request to an absolute path or relative to the CWD
app.use(express.static('dist'))
// start the server
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`))
```

**Execute**

`node server.js`

Comment: Do you know what are the benefits of express (compared to serve) for static file serving?

Comment: with more complexity comes more customization

Answer (score 9):

The Vue CLI tooling (`vue-cli-service serve --mode production`) still seemed to be serving the development files for me, albeit with `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'`.

To serve the contents of `dist`, the following worked for me without having to install any extra packages (but this will depend on what you already have installed):

```
npm run build
npx serve dist
```

With custom port and SSL key/certificate:

```
npx serve dist -l 8095 --ssl-cert .\cert.pem --ssl-key .\cert-key.pem
```

You can also put this command into your `package.json`, e.g.

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "prod": "npx serve dist",
    ...
  }
```

Then just do:

```
npm run prod
```

Comment: "without having to install any extra packages" - I executed your npm/npx commands and I was asked if I wanted to install serve@x.y.z . It works after installing the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Build should be deployed to the server, Hence, I don't think that there is any inbuilt way in vue-cli to run build locally.

To run build locally, we need to configure the server separately and run the build on the server as follow,

1) Install lite server via below command

```
$ npm install -g lite-server
```

2) Add below scripts in package.json

```
"lite": "lite-server –port 10001",    
"start": "npm run lite"
```

3) In root directory create bs-config.js file and add below script

```
module.exports = {
  port: 3000,
  server: {
    baseDir: './dist'
  }
}
```

4) Lastly, Run it via below command

```
$ npm run start
```