# Vue JS Build not Import CSS Files

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2

My CSS code that I imported into my Vue project and runs in the "npm run serve" section does not work on my server after "npm run build". What could be the reason for this? When I open the index file in the dist file on the local computer, it says CSS is missing, it does not say any error on the server.

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VRouter from './router'
import VStore from './configurations/storeConfiguration'
import V18n from './configurations/languageConfiguration'

// Special CSS Library ( UA )
import "./assets/scss/ua.css";
```

The CSS file that appears appears in the development environment. However, it does not appear in the server environment.

package.json

```
  {
      "name": "driver",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "sideEffects": false,
      "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
        "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^2.0.0",
        "axios": "^0.20.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.17.3",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "epic-spinners": "^1.1.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "sass": "^1.27.0",
        "sass-loader": "^10.0.3",
        "scriptjs": "^2.5.9",
        "sweet-modal-vue": "^2.0.0",
        "v-mask": "^2.2.3",
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-analytics": "^5.22.1",
        "vue-ctk-date-time-picker": "^2.5.0",
        "vue-i18n": "^8.22.0",
        "vue-input-mask": "0.0.11",
        "vue-router": "^3.4.7",
        "vue-suggestion": "^1.1.0",
        "vue-sweetalert2": "^4.0.0",
        "vue-the-mask": "^0.11.1",
        "vue-toastification": "^1.7.8",
        "vuex": "^3.5.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "eslint": "^6.7.2",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "root": true,
        "env": {
          "node": true
        },
        "extends": [
          "plugin:vue/essential",
          "eslint:recommended"
        ],
        "parserOptions": {
          "parser": "babel-eslint"
        },
        "rules": {}
      },
      "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not dead"
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first:
npm run serve does not serve the content of your dist file
Check: [How to run production site after build vue cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034452/how-to-run-production-site-after-build-vue-cli)

Would you mind show some code so we can analyse your problem?

Comment: Try importing the css to your index.html file

Comment: When I do this, the CSS Codes in my test environment are also not working. It happens as on the server.

Comment: I have also sent the SRC Folder to the server and the problem is resolved. Thank you..

Comment: I only deployed nuxt apps on static server and I never had to deploy the src folder, just the content of the dist folder