# How to debug a vue application after yarn build

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue application which runs correctly when I use `yarn server`.
However, after build, I keep getting error messages:

> chunk-vendors.js:49 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')

Since this is a built application, I do not have the source to debug it.
Any idea as to the problem or ideas how to debug a built application?

Comment: The question is labeled as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034452/how-to-run-production-site-after-build-vue-cli , but in fact it's not.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It's unknown what's your setup. Vue itself has nothing to do with build process. Regardless, you can check the code that caused the error by clicking on call stack entry. Even if it's minified, it can be autoformatted and intelligible enough to see the source of the problem

Comment: Thanks Estus. indeed, the the dupe question is different. ill try using the call stack to debug it.