# Vue - After build pages don't load

Tags: vue.js, vite

I've a Vue project buit with vite.

While debbuging the app, everything works ok.

But when i build it to production, and try to open it with preview, the chrome windows hangs loading forever.

Nothing is show on console. Is there anyway to capture the error?

Looks like it's stuck in a forever loop.

**Edit**

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "vue-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run build:icons && vite --host --port 5050",
    "build": "npm run build:icons && vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview --port 5050",
    "typecheck": "vue-tsc --noEmit",
    "lint": "eslint src -c .eslintrc.js --fix --rulesdir eslint-internal-rules/ --ext .ts,.js,.vue,.tsx,.jsx",
    "build:icons": "tsc -b src/@iconify && node src/@iconify/build-icons.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@casl/ability": "^6.2.0",
    "@casl/vue": "^2.2.0",
    "@codemirror/highlight": "^0.19.8",
    "@codemirror/lang-html": "^6.1.2",
    "@codemirror/lang-javascript": "^6.1.0",
    "@codemirror/lang-json": "^6.0.0",
    "@codemirror/lint": "^6.0.0",
    "@codemirror/theme-one-dark": "^6.1.0",
    "@floating-ui/dom": "1.0.0",
    "@formkit/auto-animate": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@mdi/font": "^7.0.96",
    "@vueuse/core": "^8.9.4",
    "apexcharts-clevision": "^3.28.5",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.21.2",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "pinia": "^2.0.22",
    "prismjs": "^1.29.0",
    "sass": "^1.54.9",
    "unplugin-vue-define-options": "^0.6.2",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "vue": "3.2.41",
    "vue-chartjs": "^4.1.1",
    "vue-codemirror": "^6.1.1",
    "vue-flatpickr-component": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.2.2",
    "vue-prism-component": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.6",
    "vue3-apexcharts": "^1.4.1",
    "vue3-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.6.0",
    "vuetify": "^3.0.0",
    "webfontloader": "^1.6.28"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@antfu/eslint-config-vue": "^0.25.2",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/vue3": "^5.11.2",
    "@iconify-json/mdi": "^1.1.33",
    "@iconify/tools": "^2.1.0",
    "@iconify/vue": "^3.2.1",
    "@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.186",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.18",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "@types/webfontloader": "^1.6.34",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.38.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.38.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.1.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8.23.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.5.1",
    "postcss-html": "^1.5.0",
    "stylelint": "^14.12.0",
    "stylelint-config-idiomatic-order": "^8.1.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss": "^5.0.0",
    "stylelint-use-logical-spec": "^4.1.0",
    "type-fest": "^2.19.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3",
    "unplugin-auto-import": "^0.10.3",
    "unplugin-vue-components": "^0.21.2",
    "vite": "^3.2.2",
    "vite-plugin-pages": "^0.27.1",
    "vite-plugin-vue-layouts": "^0.7.0",
    "vite-plugin-vuetify": "1.0.0",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.0.9"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@1.22.18",
  "resolutions": {
    "postcss": "8",
    "stylelint-order": "5",
    "postcss-sorting": "^7.0.1"
  }
}
```

**output of build**

```bash
╭─ ♥ 22:14 |   E:                 code
╰─ npm run build

> vue-project@0.0.0 build
> npm run build:icons && vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build


> vue-project@0.0.0 build:icons
> tsc -b src/@iconify && node src/@iconify/build-icons.js

Bundled icons from E:\_Development\_repos\hiperstream\hiperstreamCloudPlatform\cloud-platform\code\node_modules\@iconify-json\mdi\icons.json
Saved src/@iconify/icons-bundle.js (2848016 bytes)
vite v3.2.2 building for production...
transforming (253) node_modules\vuetify\lib\composables\ssrBoot.mjs[plugin:vite:esbuild] Duplicate key "key" in object literal
50 |                    ? _withDirectives((_openBlock(), _createBlock(_resolveDynamicComponent(_unref(config).app.enableI18n ? 'i18n-t' : 'span'), _mergeProps({
51 |                        key: 0,
52 |                        key: "badge",
   |                        ^
53 |                        class: ["nav-item-badge", __props.item.badgeClass]
54 |                      }, _unref(dynamicI18nProps)(__props.item.badgeContent, 'span')), {

✓ 1193 modules transformed.
dist/assets/avatar-1.aac046b6.png                                                                      15.96 KiB
dist/assets/avatar-2.0ae005f8.png                                                                      22.59 KiB
dist/assets/pose-f-28.a182fba0.png                                                                     9.21 KiB
dist/assets/pose-f-3.a3617bf1.png                                                                      8.31 KiB
dist/assets/mac-pc.4e376c3f.png                                                                        140.24 KiB
dist/assets/pose-f-39.43496c42.png                                                                     6.65 KiB
dist/assets/pose-m-14.a95cbb6a.png                                                                     5.87 KiB
dist/assets/pose-m-5.d7160542.png                                                                      6.80 KiB
dist/assets/pose-m-34.cb61966e.png                                                                     7.35 KiB
dist/assets/avatar-3.3ef9169b.png                                                                      11.57 KiB
dist/assets/avatar-4.406ee6ab.png                                                                      20.73 KiB
dist/assets/avatar-5.bad78850.png                                                                      18.35 KiB
dist/assets/avatar-6.3bc22d4b.png                                                                      18.22 KiB
dist/assets/avatar-7.8807e18e.png                                                                      18.07 KiB
dist/assets/avatar-8.942ae414.png                                                                      16.39 KiB
dist/assets/auth-v2-login-illustration-bordered-dark.1621a082.png                                      67.92 KiB
dist/assets/auth-v2-login-illustration-bordered-light.5efb7928.png                                     64.49 KiB
dist/assets/auth-v2-login-illustration-dark.c163247b.png                                               67.13 KiB
dist/assets/auth-v2-login-illustration-light.c910569c.png                                              68.40 KiB
dist/assets/paypal.8c1354c3.svg                                                                        2.24 KiB
dist/assets/illustration-1.20d12d31.png                                                                12.84 KiB
dist/assets/illustration-2.042b082c.png                                                                11.76 KiB
dist/assets/pose-fs-9.c6abbba4.png                                                                     28.74 KiB
dist/assets/sitting-girl-with-laptop-dark.aa688fe5.png                                                 9.07 KiB
dist/assets/sitting-girl-with-laptop-light.bd520dbb.png                                                9.82 KiB
dist/assets/card-meetup.c5ffac4a.png                                                                   195.24 KiB
dist/assets/html5.ff3e7cf8.png                                                                         4.78 KiB
dist/assets/python.1d56c267.png                                                                        4.16 KiB
dist/assets/react.52bd27c0.png                                                                         5.31 KiB
dist/assets/vue.33fa8801.png                                                                           4.07 KiB
dist/assets/xamarin.d2086975.png                                                                       4.08 KiB
dist/assets/chrome.391a2294.png                                                                        7.47 KiB
dist/assets/american-express.2c04e485.png                                                              8.14 KiB
dist/assets/knowledge-base-bg-dark.9e1eb36c.png                                                        29.65 KiB
dist/assets/pricing-tree-1.61561baa.png                                                                4.86 KiB
dist/assets/pricing-tree-3.7c67f762.png                                                                5.59 KiB
dist/index.html                                                                                        1.07 KiB
dist/assets/useGenerateImageVariant.ec010ed6.js                                                        0.58 KiB / gzip: 0.27 KiB
dist/assets/VCard.b6709399.js                                                                          9.07 KiB / gzip: 2.06 KiB
dist/assets/VAlert.c1a0a22c.js                                                                         5.83 KiB / gzip: 1.70 KiB
dist/assets/webfontloader.b777d690.js                                                                  19.47 KiB / gzip: 5.78 KiB
dist/assets/VForm.45e996af.js                                                                          1.47 KiB / gzip: 0.61 KiB
dist/assets/VCheckbox.e52cedcf.js                                                                      1.67 KiB / gzip: 0.64 KiB
dist/assets/login.e1da9684.js                                                                          23.87 KiB / gzip: 8.25 KiB
dist/assets/blank.c23886c7.js                                                                          0.36 KiB / gzip: 0.24 KiB
dist/assets/VWindow.74c52ec5.js                                                                        9.08 KiB / gzip: 2.56 KiB
dist/assets/VWindowItem.f856cfbe.js                                                                    3.54 KiB / gzip: 1.11 KiB
dist/assets/VTabs.dffdacbb.js                                                                          20.22 KiB / gzip: 4.81 KiB
dist/assets/VTable.d527e358.js                                                                         1.56 KiB / gzip: 0.62 KiB
dist/assets/AppPricing.63e41703.js                                                                     14.20 KiB / gzip: 6.06 KiB
dist/assets/useInvoiceStore.3f404cbb.js                                                                0.75 KiB / gzip: 0.36 KiB
dist/assets/sitting-girl-with-laptop-light.2ab0b492.js                                                 0.25 KiB / gzip: 0.14 KiB
dist/assets/useLayoutsStore.7257820e.js                                                                1.61 KiB / gzip: 0.62 KiB
dist/assets/VContainer.cf5a234e.js                                                                     0.52 KiB / gzip: 0.30 KiB
dist/assets/VTimelineItem.c57c8a72.js                                                                  7.16 KiB / gzip: 1.81 KiB
dist/assets/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.e5a66098.js                                                        5.45 KiB / gzip: 1.89 KiB
dist/assets/index.21f4736b.js                                                                          42.20 KiB / gzip: 7.63 KiB
dist/assets/VTextarea.51d5864e.js                                                                      9.17 KiB / gzip: 2.56 KiB
dist/assets/_id_.30711c66.js                                                                           31.52 KiB / gzip: 4.48 KiB
dist/assets/index.aac33ec4.js                                                                          0.89 KiB / gzip: 0.46 KiB
dist/assets/index.9ba56bbe.js                                                                          28.73 KiB / gzip: 4.65 KiB
dist/assets/DefaultTabCrudLayout.vue_vue_type_script_setup_true_lang.c9f21d22.js                       2.76 KiB / gzip: 0.97 KiB
dist/assets/DefaultCrudTabCardAccordionContentLayout.vue_vue_type_script_setup_true_lang.4411eb1b.js   5.70 KiB / gzip: 1.18 KiB
dist/assets/index.93a7da00.js                                                                          0.91 KiB / gzip: 0.47 KiB
dist/assets/VExpansionPanel.a3e74888.js                                                                8.09 KiB / gzip: 2.00 KiB
dist/assets/pricing.3cf2db40.js                                                                        17.59 KiB / gzip: 2.80 KiB
dist/assets/Layout.vue_vue_type_script_setup_true_lang.59dd5321.js                                     39.91 KiB / gzip: 7.26 KiB
dist/assets/DefaultCrudTabCardAccordionContentLayout.a1cdd194.js                                       0.42 KiB / gzip: 0.23 KiB
dist/assets/faq.76ac9c5f.js                                                                            12.59 KiB / gzip: 2.88 KiB
dist/assets/DefaultCrudTabContentVCardLayout.ee966228.js                                               1.09 KiB / gzip: 0.51 KiB
dist/assets/DefaultVCardLayout.vue_vue_type_script_setup_true_lang.c0c59562.js                         2.17 KiB / gzip: 0.78 KiB
dist/assets/DefaultLayoutWithHorizontalNav.fd6f082f.js                                                 0.12 KiB / gzip: 0.10 KiB
dist/assets/DefaultLayoutWithVerticalNav.e139d247.js                                                   0.12 KiB / gzip: 0.10 KiB
dist/assets/DefaultTabCrudLayout.df749d43.js                                                           0.31 KiB / gzip: 0.18 KiB
dist/assets/NavBarI18n.8a521c1b.js                                                                     0.12 KiB / gzip: 0.10 KiB
dist/assets/DefaultVCardLayout.dfa4f164.js                                                             0.31 KiB / gzip: 0.17 KiB
dist/assets/NavBarNotifications.d9e7daac.js                                                            0.12 KiB / gzip: 0.10 KiB
dist/assets/NavbarThemeSwitcher.c87d20bf.js                                                            0.12 KiB / gzip: 0.10 KiB
dist/assets/UserProfile.8b5cee81.js                                                                    0.12 KiB / gzip: 0.10 KiB
dist/assets/login.21c684c6.css                                                                         0.62 KiB / gzip: 0.26 KiB
dist/assets/VCardCrudTabContentLayout.abe161c0.js                                                      1.66 KiB / gzip: 0.63 KiB
dist/assets/VAlert.12d954e1.css                                                                        4.68 KiB / gzip: 1.17 KiB
dist/assets/VCard.782c479c.css                                                                         6.74 KiB / gzip: 1.52 KiB
dist/assets/blank.21020790.css                                                                         0.06 KiB / gzip: 0.07 KiB
dist/assets/VCheckbox.de0921d5.css                                                                     0.13 KiB / gzip: 0.12 KiB
dist/assets/_tab_.960e3200.css                                                                         0.43 KiB / gzip: 0.24 KiB
dist/assets/VTabs.a70cd9cf.css                                                                         3.04 KiB / gzip: 0.82 KiB
dist/assets/VWindow.1bd1bd93.css                                                                       2.15 KiB / gzip: 0.51 KiB
dist/assets/EnableOneTimePasswordDialog.a42d412e.css                                                   2.25 KiB / gzip: 0.63 KiB
dist/assets/AppPricing.61deeeed.css                                                                    0.06 KiB / gzip: 0.07 KiB
dist/assets/index.6b7aa9ad.css                                                                         0.46 KiB / gzip: 0.17 KiB
dist/assets/crm.95f00275.css                                                                           0.51 KiB / gzip: 0.31 KiB
dist/assets/VTable.4c8b70a0.css                                                                        5.63 KiB / gzip: 0.86 KiB
dist/assets/_id_.43495c33.css                                                                          0.43 KiB / gzip: 0.23 KiB
dist/assets/VTextarea.5dc8269a.css                                                                     1.36 KiB / gzip: 0.46 KiB
dist/assets/VTimelineItem.07999e79.css                                                                 16.35 KiB / gzip: 1.70 KiB
dist/assets/VExpansionPanel.da2668ed.css                                                               6.40 KiB / gzip: 1.21 KiB
dist/assets/pricing.56987cf6.css                                                                       0.43 KiB / gzip: 0.25 KiB
dist/assets/faq.c2655a3e.css                                                                           0.37 KiB / gzip: 0.23 KiB
dist/assets/_id_.85426b33.css                                                                          0.53 KiB / gzip: 0.28 KiB
dist/assets/AppDateTimePicker.2e517c19.css                                                             24.49 KiB / gzip: 3.87 KiB
dist/assets/_tab_.85a982d6.js                                                                          114.32 KiB / gzip: 17.83 KiB
dist/assets/EnableOneTimePasswordDialog.vue_vue_type_script_setup_true_lang.e28f045b.js                54.21 KiB / gzip: 26.72 KiB
dist/assets/AppDateTimePicker.vue_vue_type_style_index_0_lang.7a89fa00.js                              102.95 KiB / gzip: 22.96 KiB
dist/assets/_id_.0d3c91dd.js                                                                           131.99 KiB / gzip: 24.15 KiB
dist/assets/index.60024895.css                                                                         440.04 KiB / gzip: 56.52 KiB
dist/assets/crm.b882faf7.js                                                                            723.03 KiB / gzip: 157.73 KiB
dist/assets/index.fc5e085d.js                                                                          4054.75 KiB / gzip: 978.41 KiB
```

**output of preview**

```bash
╰─ npm run preview

> vue-project@0.0.0 preview
> vite preview --port 5050

  ➜  Local:   http://127.0.0.1:5050/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
```

The page on browser after build and preview

[image]

Comment: Any luck so far? Please let me know, I happen to stuck on this one too!

Comment: I've answered the question after I found the solution. The application was running into a infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was happening because, as I expected, the application was in a infinite loop.

The application firstly was using dynamic routes created using **vite-plugin-pages**

This was generating some problems during build, then I manually wrote the routes. Unfortunally I did forget to add the basic permissions to vue **@casl**

```js
meta: {action:'read', subject:'Auth'},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't  serve your vue build with live Server

This question is already Answered here [How to run production site after build vue cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034452/how-to-run-production-site-after-build-vue-cli)

Comment: I've tried to serve it with nginx too, but no success..

Comment: Try following the steps the link

Comment: The same problem is happening

Comment: can share the project on github let me take look(if its to large to share here)

Comment: Unfortunally i can't because it's from the company I work for.  I can share small files if needed

Comment: let's see your package.json build script

Comment: if you run build and then run preview what happens?

Comment: i've just updated the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249237/discussion-between-theodore-and-vinicius-andrade).