# Production site of Vue using Webpack show empty page

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I am working on a Vue project using Webpack. While I was developing, I was running:

```
nodemon src/index.js
webpack --mode development --watch
```

Now I finished my project and I want to upload it to a shared hosting. So what I did is run:

```
webpack --mode production
```

And it creates an index.html and a bundle.js. The problem I am facing is that if I try to open the index.html file it shows a blank page instead of my project.

Any ideas of what I have to do next?

This is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app/index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/src/public/js',
        //path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                  'vue-style-loader',
                  'css-loader',
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                      outputPath: 'images',
                      name: '/images/[name].[ext]'
                    },
                  },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: __dirname + '/src/public/index.html', // Use your custom template if needed
        }),
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run production site after build vue cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034452/how-to-run-production-site-after-build-vue-cli)

Comment: production files are meant to be served by an HTTP web server, not opened locally in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you open `index.html` in text editors, what you see is expected. By default, Vue app renders content on the client-side, not the server-side. You can use [SSR](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html) to render pages on the server-side if you want.

If you directly open the `index.html` in browser, what you see is expected too. Because you're using `file:` schema but only `http:` and `https:` is supported.